# C#'s LINQ and .NET Framework, which one depends on the other?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I think of C# language compiler as a self contained black box capable of understanding text of a certain syntax and producing compiled code. On the other hand .NET framework is a massive library that contains functionality written partly by C# and partly by C++. So .NET framework depends on C# language, not the other way around.

But I cannot fit this into how LINQ works. LINQ queries are text of a particular syntax that C# compiler can understand. But to build by own LINQ provider I need to work with interfaces like IQueryable and IQueryProvider both of which are defined in System.Linq namespace of the framework.

Does that mean a functionality C# language offers is dependent on a part of .NET framework? Does C# language know about .NET framework?

Comment: LINQ isn't a merely a framework. The language is modified with features such as extension methods, `yield`, lambda expressions etc.

Comment: They are all dependant on each other.

Comment: I am not saying LINQ is a framework. I am trying to understand how LINQ works.

Comment: If you want to understand it: https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Edulinq/default.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> LINQ queries are text of a particular syntax that C# compiler can understand.

Well, *query expressions* are - but the compiler doesn't really "understand" them. It just translates them in a pretty mechanical manner. For example, take this query:

```
var query = from foo in bar
            where foo.X > 10
            select foo.Y;
```

That is translated into:

```
var query = bar.Where(foo => foo.X > 10)
               .Select(foo => foo.Y);
```

The compiler doesn't know *anything* about what `Where` and `Select` mean here. They don't even have to be methods - if you had appropriate fields or properties of delegate types, the compiler would be fine with it. Basically, if the second form will compile, so will the query expression.

Most LINQ providers use *extension methods* to provide these methods (`Where`, `Select`, `SelectMany` etc). Again, they're just part of the C# language - the compiler doesn't know or care what the extension methods *do*.

For more details about how query expressions are translated, see [part 41 of my Edulinq blog series](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/28/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-41-how-query-expressions-work.aspx). You may find the rest of my Edulinq series informative, too - it's basically a series of blog posts in which I reimplement LINQ to Objects, one method at a time. Again, this demonstrates that the C# compiler doesn't rely on the LINQ implementation being in the `System.Linq` namespace, or anything like that.

Comment: OK, since "where" and "select" are extension methods (of IQueryable<T>) that compiler does not know about, how does the compiler force the syntax of a LINQ expression? What makes the compiler decide that it is a query expression? Is it the "from" keyword? Where does IQueryable<T> fit in this picture? (I will definitely read your blog series in a convenient time and I am sure I will have many 'aha!' moments.)

Comment: @e-mre: Yes, the compiler knows it's a query expression because it starts with "from" and it's not used in a context where it's valid in any other way. (That's not a keyword - just a contextual keyword. You can still have a variable called `from`, but `from x in y` is never going to be valid as a non-query-expression, unless you had a type called `from` and you were in a `foreach` statement...) `IQueryable<T>` comes in after translation - `Select`, `Where` etc are just called as extension methods as they would be even if you didn't use a query expression to start with.

Comment: Does that mean I can build my own IMyQueryable interface with extension methods such as "abc", "def" and I can write queries that start with "from" but call methods in IMyQueryable? Something like "from myobj in mycol abc myobj.X = 10 def myobj"

Comment: @e-mre: No, the extension methods *have* to be called `Select`, `Where` etc. The translation from query expression to "non-query-expression" LINQ is hard-coded into the C# language.

Comment: Besides EduLinq, one LINQ reimplementation example is [LINQBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx). It was written to allow programs compiled to target .Net 2.0 to use LINQ.

Answer (score 8):

.NET Framework contains of many pieces. One of the most important is CLR — Common Language Runtime. All .NET languages depend on it, C# included, because they produce IL-code which cannot be executed by machine processor. Instead, CLR executes it.

And there is also Base Class Library, BCL, which is available to use for every .NET language: C#, VB.NET, Managed C++, F#, IronRuby, you name it. I doubt it was written in C#. It doesn't depend on any features of those languages, because classes and OOP are built in CLR.

So, yes, C# language knows about .NET framework, it absolutely *must* know about it. Think about `IEnumerable`: to compile `foreach` into `GetEnumerator()`, and `MoveNext()` calls, C# compiler has to know that, well, `IEnumerable` exists. And is somewhat special.

Or think about attributes! C# compiler has the intrinsic knowledge about what methods `Attribute` interface provides.

But CLR itself doesn't know anything about C#. At all.

Comment: +1, good answer.  However, much of the BCL *was* written in C#, but that's an implementation detail.  It could have been written in any language.

Comment: So C# and .Net Framework are dependent on each other and both are dependent on CLR. I have to do some more digging on this circular dependency between C# and .Net FW but you answer is definitely a useful one. +1 upvote for it.

Comment: I am not quite sure what *you* call ".NET Framework". In my understanding, the CLR and BCL are parts of the framework, and C# language is not. Installation of .NET Framework 3.5 doesn't comes with a C# compiler.